# How do I use XMLHttpRequest to send a POST to multiple pages at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here I have my logic for sending the post but I need it to go to multiple PHP pages on different servers at the same time.

```
var bInfo = JSON.stringify(businessesFound)
//opens a connection to the database and saves data

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://website1.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(bInfo);
console.log(bInfo)
```

Comment: Put the URLs to send the data to in an array and loop through them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` are async by default. So, just send multiple times:

```
var request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
request1.open('POST', 'http://website1.php', true);
request1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
request1.send(bInfo);

var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
request2.open('POST', 'http://website2.php', true);
request2.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
request2.send(bInfo);
```

Of course, there will be an order, but the script will not be blocked waiting for the response to send the next requisition.
Or you can loop an array of urls, depending wheter is the case or not.

Comment: I'll try this and see what happens. Thank you!